# save two models from on form does not work ruby radrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rad

I'm a newbie with rad rails. I wanted to write at same time in two table from one form.

I have a table machine (with nom and role as column) and a table ipvfour (with machine_id and ip as column).

So I created in models the relation has-and-belongs-to-many.

But when I'm trying to add a new machine if failed with

unknown attribute: ip

I don't really understand why, can someone help me please ?

---

machine.controllers:

def create
    @machine = Machine.new(params[:machine])

```
ipvfour = @machine.ip.create(params[:ip])

respond_to do |format|

  if @machine.save && ipvfour.save

    flash[:notice] = 'Machine was successfully created.'

    format.html { redirect_to(@machine) }

    format.xml  { render :xml => @machine, :status => :created, :location => @machine }
```

else

format.html { render :action => "new" }

format.xml  { render :xml => @machine.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }

end

end

end

---

new.html.erb (machine)

## New machine

'form', :locals => { :f_machine => f_machine } %>

---

_form.html.erb (machine)

<% f_machine.fields_for :ip do |f_ip| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'ipvfours/form', :locals => { :f_ip => f_ip } %>
<% end %>

---

_form.html.erb (ipvfours)

`<%= f_ip.label :ip %><br />`
    `<%= f_ip.text_field :ip %>`

---

The page to add a machine is correclty displayed with all fields but it seems that write in db failed due to .... I hope that someone will be able ti help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

You can edit any model in any controller if you want. There's a magic trick called 
accepts_nested_attributes_for (google it!)

Your code should look like:

In your Controller:

```
def new 
  # .... your code ....

  # create empty machine
  @machine  = Machine.new

  # add one empty ip 
  @machine.ipvfours.build

  # .... your code ....

end

def create 

  # fill machine and ipvfours directly 
  @machine = Machine.new(params[:machine])

  respond_to do |format|

    if @machine.save

      flash[:notice] = 'Machine was successfully created.'

      format.html { redirect_to(@machine) }

      format.xml  { render :xml => @machine, :status => :created, :location => @machine }

    else

      format.html { render :action => "new" }

      format.xml { render :xml => @machine.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }

    end

  end

end
```

In your view:

**new.html.erb**

```
<% form_for(@machine) do |f_machine| %>  

  <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => { :f_machine => f_machine } %>

  <%= f_machine.submit 'Create' %>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', machines_path %>
```

**_form.html.erb (machine)**

```
<%= f_machine.error_messages %>

<% f_machine.fields_for :ipvfours do |f_ip| %> 
  <%= render :partial => 'ipvfours/form', :locals => { :f_ip => f_ip } %>
<% end %>
```

**_form.html.erb (ipvfours)**

```
<%= f_ip.label :ip %>
<br />
<%= f_ip.text_field :ip %>
```

In your Model:

**Machine model**

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :ipvfours, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ipvfours

end
```

best regards

simon

Comment: one things that I don't understand it where should I add your code ??
I mean that I4m using the controller of machine to write, maybe I'm wrong and I should use the ipvfours controller. How can I know whitch controller used to write ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I just saw it. Thanks. So I do exactly what you tell me but I still have one problem:

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in MachinesController#create
unknown attribute: ipvfour

Request:
{"machine"=>{"nom"=>"titi",
 "ipvfour"=>{"ip"=>"10.1.1.12"},
 "role"=>"dev"},
 "commit"=>"Create",
 "authenticity_token"=>"sEoGE2dQUlq6fPL05fTl7Whr2WYWYa34dedi/uc59sI="}

One think that is strange is the request that is done in wrong order while I'm filling nom and role and ip.

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Check this line in your machine _form.html.erb: 
<% f_machine.fields_for :ipvfours do |f_ip| %> are you sure you DID write :ipvfours (plural!!) seems like you wrote :ipvfour (singular!)

Comment: By the way: the order the fields are sent to your controller doesn't matter the nesting is important, means the "ipvfours" has to be inside of the "machine" ;)

Comment: if I do that I cannot see ip fields in my new machine page. I do not really understand why.

Comment: Hi, did you put the @machine.ipvfours.build in your "new" action?

Comment: @machine.ipvfours.build  I set this but I have one error

undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

Comment: this means @machine.ipvfours does not exists! 1) make sure you have this in your machine model: has_many :ipvfours 2) make sure you have @machine = Machine.new in your new action before you do @machine.ipvfours.build

Comment: yes that works thank you very much for your help. I think now I can understand better the process. Thanks again.